# completableFuture whenComplete strange behavior

Tags: java, completable-future

I face some strange behavior while using completableFutures
See my code snippet below for easy and better understanding.
I iterate through list of messages and call handleMessage on each message.
handleMessage method first calls getDataContentIdByService and finally mappingService.process method is called.

But the issue is once `getDataContentIdByService` method processing is done, before execution of mappingService.process method is complete, the call is returned back to whenComplete stage.

What i want is both getDataContentIdByService and mappingService.process methods should finish the execution in sequence and then whenComplete stage should be called.

Is something wrong in my code .. or? can someone help?

```
Completablefuture.allOf(messages.getList().stream()
        .filter(this::msgOkOrLog)
        .filter(this::notOnDenyList)
        .map(msg -> handleMessage(msg, messages.getTrackingIdentifier(), messages.getMessageType()))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new))
      .whenComplete((input, exception) -> countErrorsInContainer(messages));
```

The handleMessage function

```
    protected CompletableFuture<Void> handleMessage(InternalProxyMessage message,
        TrackingIdentifier containerTid, MessageType messageType) {
    return getDataContentIdByService(message)
                       .thenAccept(message::setContentId)
                       .thenAccept(  
              mappingService.process(message)
                      .exceptionally(
                              ex -> {
                                  throw new InternalServerErrorException("Unmanaged Error", ex);
                                }
                              })));
    }
```

Comment: `getDataContentIdByService()` is giving a `Future` object. Can you try `thenApply` instead of `thenAccept` ?

Comment: Try using CompletableFuture.allOf() instead of whenComplete(). The former will wait for all the futures to complete.

Comment: @papaya thenAccept and thenApply both return Future objects. It shouldn't make any difference. But i tried it anyway and it didn't work

Comment: @MohammadFaraz But i want to execute getDataContentIdByService method first and then mappingService.process.  But whenComplete is called on list of completableFutures (Future for each message). I edited code little bit

Comment: What does `mappingService.process(...)` return? Is it a `CompleteableFuture`? If so, what if you try `thenCompose(messageService::process)` instead of `thenAccept`?

Comment: @JMBA can you share the code of what is returned exactly from `getDataContentIdByService()` method.

Comment: @MohammadFaraz CompletableFuture<Long> is the return type of getDataContentIdByService.

Comment: @Slaw I tried thenCompose even before you commented in this post. Surprisingly it worked. But i would like to really understand how using thenCompose worked rather than using thenAccept for executing mappingService.process method. Infact i should basically understand which one to use when i guess :)

Comment: `thenCompose` is like a flat map operation. Basically it waits for the "nested" stage created by `mappingService.process(...)` to complete before completing itself. As the documentation notes, it's very similar to `Optional.flatMap` and `Stream.flatMap`. However, the `thenAccept` method does not wait. It simply launches the "nested" stage and immediately completes. Thus any dependent stages are triggered despite the "nested" stage not having completed yet.

Comment: @Slaw that's not it. `thenCompose` will not block (or wait as you say it) for anything. It's actually a very good method exactly for that - it does not block. And this questions needs a minimal, verifiable example and not some pseudo-code that does not even compile.

Comment: @Eugene I suppose you could argue "wait" is the wrong term to use here, but the `thenCompose` stage definitely does not complete until and unless the nested, or "composed", stage completes. That is a form of waiting in my opinion. Note I never said, nor meant to imply, that any thread was being blocked in the process. Everything was meant to be interpreted within the context of a chain of stages.

Comment: @Slaw then I am a bit confused of what you meant. How is `thenCompose` supposed to help if it does not block? `thenAccept` or `thenCompose` are chained to the future and _not_ executed by the chaining thread; unless the future is already completed, before the chaining. In this regard, it will make no difference to the OPs problem. I still fail to understand the exact question here and without a minim example, where we don't have to guess what is going on, I don't think we can answer it.

Comment: @Eugene Because the problem is the `whenCompete` stage is being executed too soon for the OP. They are returning the `thenAccept` stage from the method and adding it to the array passed to `allOf`. The problem with that is all the `thenAccept` stages complete before the nested stages do, thus the `allOf` stage completes too soon, ultimately leading to the `whenComplete` stage executing too soon. When using `thenCompose` the `allOf` stage only completes once all the composed stages complete. Problem, as I understood it, solved.

Comment: @Slaw they are not returning a stage, but a `CompletableFuture<Void>`. For simplicity, let's suppose it is just one. This one `CompletableFuture<Void>` is placed in an array and that array is passed to `CompletableFuture::allOf`. If we now read the documentation: "Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete". So, `whenComplete` is going to get called when all the futures are completed. `thenAccept` then says : "Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage's result". As such...

Comment: that one `CompletableFuture` that we have in the array, is going to complete when all the `thenAccept` previous ("this stage" from the documentation) stages are. Can you point me where I am wrong?

Comment: @Eugene A `CompletableFuture` is a stage. Now, to be fair, I'm making assumptions here based on the OP's description. What I believe you're missing is that `process` is returning a stage. It launches that stage asynchronously (I assume). Thus `thenAccept` simply launches the stage _and then immediately completes_. It does not "wait" for `process` to complete. Using `thenCompose`, however, does "wait" for `process` to complete.

Comment: @Slaw ah! Now it all makes sense, yes. Thank you for the follow-up, you should really make this an answer, so that I can upvote and show my appreciation for the patience.

Comment: I edited just so that I could retract my down-vote and retract my vote close - this is a valid question and it's only me to blame for not understanding it. 1+. If @Slaw does not come to answer it - I will; though he deserves the "spot on!" badge, if such existed.

Comment: Guys, Thanks for all your answers, really appreciate your help. Sorry for late reply. So according to @Slaw thenAccept would simply initiate "mappingService.process" method call and doesn't wait for completion whereas thenCompose wait for it to complete. All these days i assumed that all thenAccept, thenCompose, thenApply works the same way with different return types but i was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example could be greatly simplified:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "initiated");
    CompletableFuture<Void> cf2 = cf1.thenAccept(x -> {
        CompletableFuture<String> response = composed(x);
        return;
    });
    System.out.println("Is it done : " + cf2.isDone());
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3));

}

private static CompletableFuture<String> composed(String s) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
        System.out.println("composed is actually finished");
        return "done";
    });
}
```

When `cf1` is completed, `thenAccept` will be called; but of course since `composed` is called in a different thread (that `CompletableFuture::supplyAsync`), `return` statement will be hit before it will be finished. Running the example above reveals:

```
Is it done : true
composed is actually finished
```

On the other hand, if you change your code to :

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = cf1.thenCompose(x -> {
     CompletableFuture<String> response = composed(x);
     return response;
});
```

You are now returning the result of that `composed`. So when `cf1` is completed, `thenCompose` will be called; so `cf2` will be completed only when the inner future will.